# Cannot install Apache 2.4 from REMI repository

Tags: apache, yum

I am trying to install Apache 2.4 from the REMI repo but no matter what I try all I get is Apache 2.2

I have installed and enabled the EPEL and REMI repos:

```
# yum repolist enabled

repo id                  repo name                                                       status
base                     CentOS-6 - Base                                                 6,696
epel                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                  12,358
extras                   CentOS-6 - Extras                                               64
remi                     Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64           4,047
remi-php56               Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64   417
remi-safe                Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64      1,768
updates                  CentOS-6 - Updates                                              974
```

I then use:

```
# yum install --enablerepo=remi httpd
```

Have also tried:

```
# yum install --enablerepo=remi-php56,remi,remi-safe,epel httpd
```

but in both cases I get offered only Apache 2.2:

```
Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================
 Package              Arch            Version                           Repository        Size
===============================================================================================
Installing:
 httpd                x86_64          2.2.15-56.el6.centos.3            updates          834 k
Installing for dependencies:
 httpd-tools          x86_64          2.2.15-56.el6.centos.3            updates           79 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)

Total download size: 913 k
Installed size: 3.1 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Only the updates repo is getting used and not remi.

I have checked if apache is already installed:

```
# httpd -v
bash: httpd: command not found
# yum remove httpd*
Package(s) httpd* available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Is there something else I am missing? How do I get the REMI repo to be used? It is enabled but for some reason not active

Comment: in order to know if remi repo provides `httpd`, do the following: `yum list httpd`

Answer (score 3):

[remi](https://rpms.remirepo.net/) repository is mostly dedicated to **PHP**, and doesn't provide Apache HTTP server, but use system version instead.

Mostly because default version in base repository is well maintained, secured, and enough in most case.

Notice that an httpd24 SCL (Software Collections) is available in [centos-sclo repository](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL) which is a clone of [RHSCL](https://www.redhat.com/en/about/press-releases/red-hat-software-collections-23-and-red-hat-developer-toolset-6-now-generally-available).

Comment: Thank you - I have used the RHSCL version previously but the fact it uses different conf file locations and service name etc made it painful so I was hoping I could get a simpler way to get 2.4

Comment: Also to add - almost every guide I can find on Google to install Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6 on Centos mentions that Apache 2.4 is part of REMI. There is so much incorrect information if that is the case :/